# How to Drag and Drop the text in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried below code for drag and drop in selenium webdriver. But it's not working

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\D Drive\\Software\\Selenium Latest Software\\chromedriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://suvian.in/selenium/2.10dragAndDrop.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("title is " + driver.getTitle());

    WebElement fromDrag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[@id='drag1']/strong"));
    WebElement toDrag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div1']"));

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  act.clickAndHold(fromDrag).moveToElement(toDrag).release(toDrag).build().perform();;
```

Pls help on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: chrome browser..